# Magento Pager is not showing in product list.phtml

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, mage

In magento I override product list.phtml, its working fine but pager is not showing. I already included code in xml as well as in list.phtml for pager but not showing. Please help.

Thanks in advance

below code for list.phtml

```
$this->getToolbarHtml()
```

And for xml code

```
    <catalog_category_default translate="label">
            <reference name="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bundle.js</name></action>
            </reference>
     <reference name="content">

    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="quickview/catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
     <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                </block> 


            </reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the `catalog/category_view` block.
Try this:

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
  <reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bundle.js</name></action>
  </reference>
  <reference name="content">
    <block name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml" type="catalog/category_view">
      <block name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" type="catalog/product_list">
        <block name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml" type="catalog/product_list_toolbar">
          <block name="product_list_toolbar_pager" type="page/html_pager" />
        </block>
      </block>
    </block>
  </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```